# How can two vectors be dependent in one complex field and independent in real field?

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the vectors $v_1=(1, 1+i, i)$, $v_2=(i, -i, 1-i)$, $v_3=(0, 1-2i,2-i)$ in $\mathbb C^3$ are linearly independent in the field of real numbers but dependent over the field of complex numbers.

Comment: What are your ideas? What did you try? Where did you get stuck? This should be a matter of checking definitions.

Comment: [There's an existing question with almost the same title.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/611630)

Answer (score 1):

The vectors $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are linearly dependent in $\mathbb{K}^3$ (with $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) if there exist $a, b, c \in \mathbb{K}$ with not $a = b = c = 0$ such that:
$$ av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3 = 0 $$

it is easily checked that $v_1 + iv_2 + iv_3 = 0$, so the vectors are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{C}$. However, when $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and we have 
$ av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3 = 0 $ it follows (from checking the first coordinate of the sum) that $a + bi = 0$, so $a = b = 0$. So $cv_3 = 0$, so $c = 0$ as well. So $a = b = c = 0$ is the only solution $ av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3 = 0 $ with $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and the vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

To answer your question, this is possible because you have 'more possibilities' to choose the coefficients $a, b$, and $c$ when they are in $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I did something like this M=[v1 v2 v3]...showed det(M)=0 ..means they are dependent over the field of complex numbers and for the real part did the same as you did. Is it fine to do like this way?

Comment: Sure, if you did Gaussian elimination with complex coefficients. Both things mean essentially the same.